# how to get oauth access token for facebook using ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth-2.0, facebook-access-token

Am trying to get oauth access token for facebook programmatically in ruby.

My code is as follows:

```
client = OAuth2::Client.new(
  APP_ID,
  SECRET_ID,
  :authorize_url => "/dialog/oauth",
  :token_url => "/oauth/access_token",
  :site => "https://www.facebook.com/"
)

code = client.auth_code.authorize_url(:redirect_uri => "http://www.facebook.com/")
token = client.auth_code.get_token(code, :redirect_uri => "https://graph.facebook.com/")
OAuth2::AccessToken.new(client, token.token, {:mode => :query, :param_name =>"oauth_token"})
```

When i try to run the above ruby code, i'm getting the following exception

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?response_type=code&client_id=APP_ID
51&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2F

/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@samples/gems/oauth2-0.5.2/lib/oauth2/clie
nt.rb:129:in `get_token': OAuth2::Error (OAuth2::Error)
        from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@samples/gems/oauth2-0.5.2/li
b/oauth2/strategy/auth_code.rb:29:in `get_token'
        from oauth.rb:16:in `<main>'
```

Any help is greatly appreciated as I have spent more than a day while trying to sort this out.

Comment: any ideas are greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should raise your accept-rate for answers.

Comment: But here's something to get you started: your redirect_uri's appear to be Facebook.com's, but those should be YOUR url.

Comment: The problem remains the same when i changed my redirect_uri. My redirect_uri is (http://localhost.com:3000). Is it the problem where in redirect_uri or the problem causes some where else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to put as redirect_uri instead of `localhost:3000` your real IP address `ex. 231.61.233.57:3000`? Additionally you could try to use ssh tunneling for testing purposes so your localhost application will be available worldwide. Check this out http://progrium.com/localtunnel/ .
 When you will get ip address from this tool try to set redirect_uri param to it.

Comment: I agree that the `redirect_uri` is likely the issue. The API performing the redirect may only redirect to URIs associated with the authorized application. (I don't know if Facebook does this, but other OAuth APIs I've worked with do.)